# Resizable Window Resolution

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have an `img#myimage` whose src is *1000px x 1000px*. Then I resize it with `.css()` to *100 x 100* and apply `resizable()` to it:

```
$('#myimage').css('width' : '100px', 'height' : '100px'})
             .resizable();
```

What happens now when I expand it with the resize handles back to *1000 x 1000*? Do I still have a million pixels of resolution, or did I lose something when I reduced the width and height with `css()`?

It seems that I still have the million pixels, but I'd like to get someone else's thoughts on what's really happening here.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery does not actually resize the image, it just scales it. So when you scale it back up to 1000x1000 it will still be the full resolution (because the image hasn't actually changed).

If you wanted to actually resize and save the image you would need server-side code such as php or asp to process the image and send it back to the browser.